# Moto G XT1045 Not updating to Android 5.0

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I'm an aspiring android developer, and I would like to be able to test my apps on Android 5.0. I own a Moto G XT1045, and when i went to about phone, and software update, it said it's up to date, but the android version number said 4.4.4. I cant figure it out! And i really don't want to void my warranty by flashing the operating system. Can anybody tell me what im doing wrong?

Comment: Not a programming question.

Comment: might have to do with vendor-specific branding of the OS.

Comment: Maybe, but motorola barely touches the OS. Besides a few apps they install on it, and the change in boot screen, its pure android. Shouldn't be that hard!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has not yet released for moto g LTE(xt1045) and hence it is saying that the phone is updated. You cannot do anything unless you want to root the phone and flash the ROM(which you don't want to).

Comment: @InfiniteHappiness: This does indeed answer the question? You should pay more attention while reviewing.